# A generalized fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $f \in L^1 [0,1]$. For all $x \in [0,1]$ define $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}  f(t) \; dt$. Then My question is

Can we say that $F$ is an absolutely continuous function?   with  following derivative formula

$$F'(x) = f(x)   \quad \quad a.e \; x \in [0,1]$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Momo I made it more clear

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations

Comment: @lhf  oh Thank you

Comment: This is exactly the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem. (I'm surprised that you're studying AC functions but don't know this - I would have thought that any book covering the basic facts about AC functions would include this fact.)